# Issue removing core data entry by selecting a row on table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Using core data to populate my table view. The thing I am not getting is that how can I delete a single entry from the core data.

I am using uitableview not the controller.

Here is the code I am using:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == favouritesTable) {
    cellValue = [licensePlateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else { // handle search results table view
    cellValue = [filteredListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"vlCell";

VehicleListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Cell Created");

    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VehicleListCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[VehicleListCell class]]) {
            cell = (VehicleListCell *)currentObject;
        }
    }

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
pressRecongnizer.view.tag = indexPath.row;
    pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
    [pressRecongnizer release];
}

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

Favouritesdata *favdata = [licensePlateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[cell ignition] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ignition.png"]];
[[cell direction] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"south.png"]];

cell.licPlate.text = [favdata licenseplate];

NSLog(@"cellvalue for cellforRow: %@", cell.licPlate.text);

return cell;}
```

In the method of UILongPressGestureRecognizer:

```
- (void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}

VehicleListCell* cell = (VehicleListCell *)[recognizer view];

cellValueForLongPress = cell.licPlate.text;

NSLog(@"cell value: %@", cellValueForLongPress);

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;
alert.tag = recognizer.view.tag;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Remove from Favourites"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Take to Map"];

[alert show];}
```

here in alert view method the selected row will be deleted (if([title isEqualToString:@"Remove from Favourites"])):

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

NSString *title = [alert buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

NSManagedObjectContext *contextFav = [app managedObjectContext];
Favouritesdata * favourites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favouritesdata" inManagedObjectContext:contextFav];

if([title isEqualToString:@"Remove from Favourites"])
{
    NSLog(@"cellValueForLongPress: %@", cellValueForLongPress);
///////// to remove the object from core data
    [licensePlateArray removeObjectAtIndex:alert.tag];

}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"Take to Map"])
{
    NSLog(@"Go to MapView");
}

NSError *error;

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error Occured");
}
[favouritesTable reloadData];}
```

Comment: remove that object from that index from your array and then reload table.

Comment: can you please help me with code example

Comment: Please See answer and if don't getting then let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
    pressRecongnizer.view.tag = indexPath.row;
    pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
    [pressRecongnizer release];
```

and use alertview like this

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;
alert.tag = recognizer.view.tag;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Remove from Favourites"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Take to Map"];    
[alert show];
```

then write this in `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

```
[YourArray removeObjectAtIndex:alert.tag];    
[YourTable reloadData];
```

Please use this code at appropriate place in your code..

Happy Coding..

Comment: Now I have got one more issue, entries are getting deleted and new table get load properly but now when I reload the whole view it is showing the entries again, which were deleted ... what can be the issue ..

Comment: can you help me in it.... that where the issue would be, like in app delegate methods or in elsewhere, because I am saving my data in one controller and fetching it in another controller, because in cellForRowAtIndexPath table is being populated from core data, if it is deleted then the core data should be empty

Comment: then remove that object from the root array which you are using in UITableview

Comment: how to remove each object which is being deleted from table view, should also from core data

Comment: using : removeObjectAtIndex for array

Comment: I have used this code as u suggested:

[YourArray removeObjectAtIndex:alert.tag];    
[YourTable reloadData];

Comment: I have edited my question as you suggested for the code ... but its not removing the object from core data

Comment: put debug point in -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
and see this method calls or not

Comment: Try using NSLog that are you getting alertview's tag??

Comment: I have tried and this is the value

NSLog(@"alert.tag:::: %d", alert.tag); 
alert.tag:::: 0

Comment: It means you are getting wrong tag just try with debug you will get 100% solution as this is the simplest code for doing this